# Indexed views & Nhibernate - NOEXPAND Hint?

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possible to configure NHibernate to issue the NOEXPAND hint when it executes a select statement against an indexed view?  SQL Server always skips the views and goes straight to the base tables when executing queries unless the hint is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hack I tried and it worked.  Just added (NOEXPAND) to the "table" name.

```
<class name="ClassName" mutable="false" table="vw_ViewName (NOEXPAND)">
...
</class>
```