# Does SQL azure use NOEXPAND by default?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, azure

I am using clustered index view in SQL azure. I use Hibernate to query this view.
Will Azure automatically use `WITH ( NOEXPAND )` feature? If not , how do I do it in Hibernate? I cannot add `WITH ( NOEXPAND )` to the hibernate query as it is giving me a syntax error.

```
IllegalArgumentException occured : org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: WITH near line 1
```

Comment: I am not using XML hibernate mapping. I use the @Entity annotation in the Class. So how can I annotate to use NOEXPAND?

Answer (score 0):

You can add  (NOEXPAND) to your table name if you'd like to use hint. Please see this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6281523/4836342).

> Will Azure automatically use WITH ( NOEXPAND ) feature? If not , how do I do it in Hibernate?

As I known, SQL Azure don't use this feature automatically. If you want to use it, you need [specify the NOEXPAND hint.](http://www.sqlservice.se/indexed-views-in-sql-azure/)

Comment: I am not using XML hibernate mapping. I use the @Entity annotation in the Class. So how can I annotate to use NOEXPAND?

Comment: You could also add (NOEXPAND) into your query. For example, you can use HQL like " SELECT * FROM vw.indexview(noexpand) ". Please try it.

Comment: "SELECT r FROM vw.indexview(noexpand) r " does not work. it gives syntax error in Hibernate. When I remove "noexpand", syntax error is gone

Answer (score 0):

By default, it does not use the "WITH (NOEXPAND)" feature. Did you try adding it in the annotation? Does it give any error?